# PHP how to do a list of keyvalue pairs?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a data structure like this:

```
pos, desc, price
0  , myKey, myValue
1  , myKey2, myvalue
```

So I can look through the array using a foreach, and get the key and value.

Should be easy but I am stuggling, this is what I've tried:

```
$variationsList = array();

for($x=1;$x<6;$x++)
    {
        if (get_post_meta($post_id, "variationDesc" . $x, true) != '')
        {
            $variationsList["desc"] = get_post_meta($post_id, "variationDesc" . $x, true);
            $variationList["price"] = get_post_meta($post_id, "variationPrice" . $x, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not meaning to belittle anyone, but I find it hard to believe that a user with 10k+ reputation has problems with the basics of array manipulation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Append* a new array containing these two keys to your array:

```
$variationsList[] = array('desc' => ..., 'price' => ...);
```